# Manipulation XML having array in it

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an incoming XML i wanted transform to another format . I am not getting desired result .

Incoming XML:

```
<aggResponse>
   <services>
      <serviceIdentifier>vStatus</serviceIdentifier>
      <Access>Allow</Access>
   </services>
   <services>
      <serviceIdentifier>vAccess</serviceIdentifier>
      <Access>Reject</Access>
      <ErrorCode>200504</ErrorCode>
   </services>
   <services>
      <serviceIdentifier>vLavel</serviceIdentifier>
      <Access>Allow</Access>
   </services>
</aggResponse>
```

Need Output:

```
<NS1:Response xmlns:NS1="http://test.com">
   <NS1:checkDetail>
      <NS1:Detail>
         <NS1:AuthCheckType>vStatus</NS1:AuthCheckType>
         <NS1:Result>Allow</NS1:Result>
         <NS1:ErrorCode />
         <NS1:checkDetail />
      </NS1:Detail>
      <NS1:Detail>
         <NS1:AuthCheckType>vAccess</NS1:AuthCheckType>
         <NS1:Result>Allow</NS1:Result>
         <NS1:ErrorCode />
         <NS1:checkDetail />
      </NS1:Detail>
      <NS1:Detail>
         <NS1:AuthCheckType>vLavel</NS1:AuthCheckType>
         <NS1:Result>Reject</NS1:Result>
         <NS1:ErrorCode>200504</NS1:ErrorCode>
         <NS1:checkDetail />
      </NS1:Detail>
   </NS1:checkDetail>
   <NS1:Access>Reject</NS1:Access>
   <NS1:ErrorCode>200504</NS1:ErrorCode>
</NS1:Response>
```

I am using the below XSLT to transform.
XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp dpconfig">
   <xsl:output method="xml" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="overallAccess" select="'Allow'" />
      <xsl:variable name="errorCode" select="0" />
      <NS1:Response xmlns:NS1="http://test.com">
         <NS1:checkDetail>
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='aggResponse']/*[local-name()='services']">
               <NS1:Detail>
                  <NS1:AuthCheckType>
                     <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='serviceIdentifier']" />
                  </NS1:AuthCheckType>
                  <NS1:Result>
                     <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='Access']" />
                  </NS1:Result>
                  <NS1:ErrorCode>
                     <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='ErrorCode']" />
                  </NS1:ErrorCode>
                  <xsl:variable name="overallAccesstemp">
                     <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='Access']" />
                  </xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:variable name="authAccess">
                     <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$overallAccesstemp='Reject'">
                           <xsl:variable name="overallAccess" select="'Reject'" />
                           <xsl:variable name="errorCode" select="*[local-name()='ErrorCode']" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$overallAccesstemp='Reject_needmorepoint' and $overallAccess='Allow' ">
                           <xsl:variable name="overallAccess" select="'Reject_needmorepoint'" />
                           <xsl:variable name="errorCode" select="*[local-name()='ErrorCode']" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                           <xsl:variable name="overallAccess" select="'Allow'" />
                           <xsl:variable name="errorCode" select="0" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                     </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:variable>
                  <NS1:checkDetail />
               </NS1:Detail>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </NS1:checkDetail>
         <NS1:Access>
            <xsl:value-of select="$authAccess" />
         </NS1:Access>
         <NS1:ErrorCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="$errorCode" />
         </NS1:ErrorCode>
      </NS1:Response>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Incoming XML is dynamic one meaning the  "Access" tag value can be either 1. Allow 2. Reject 3. Reject_morepoint. . condition  1.so if all are like Allow then final Access is "Allow"  condition 2. if at least one is Reject then final Access is Reject . Condition 3 if all are Reject_morepoint then final Access is Reject_morepoint.  For Allow error code will be always 0 and all other case it should be the error code we are getting from incoming request .That is why i was trying to write the logic within for loop which is not quite working.

Can someone let me know what is the issue in the xslt. How to get the desired result

Comment: I believe the output you show is mistaken: `<NS1:Result>Reject</NS1:Result>` and `<NS1:ErrorCode>200504</NS1:ErrorCode>` should be under `<NS1:AuthCheckType>vAccess</NS1:AuthCheckType>`, not `<NS1:AuthCheckType>vLavel</NS1:AuthCheckType>`.

Comment: Yes you are right i have wrongly placed the elements it should be under vAccess

Comment: The conditions you have added are not collectively exhaustive: You have no result for a combination of Allow and Reject_morepoint. -- P.S. There is no need for a loop to test these conditions. Not to mention that `xsl:for-each` is not a loop.

Comment: Yah we can have combination of Allow and Reject_morepoint also in that case also final Access would be Reject_morepoint . Not sure how we can do without loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you cannot do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/aggResponse">
    <NS1:Response xmlns:NS1="http://test.com">
        <NS1:checkDetail>
            <xsl:for-each select="services">
                <NS1:Detail>
                    <NS1:AuthCheckType>
                        <xsl:value-of select="serviceIdentifier"/>
                    </NS1:AuthCheckType>
                    <NS1:Result>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Access"/>
                    </NS1:Result>
                    <NS1:ErrorCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ErrorCode"/>
                    </NS1:ErrorCode>
                    <NS1:checkDetail/>
                </NS1:Detail>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </NS1:checkDetail>
        <xsl:variable name="access" select="services[serviceIdentifier='vAccess']" />
        <NS1:Access>
            <xsl:value-of select="$access/Access" />
        </NS1:Access>
        <NS1:ErrorCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="$access/ErrorCode" />
        </NS1:ErrorCode>
    </NS1:Response>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. There should **never** be a reason to use a hack like `*[local-name()='xyz']`.

---

***Added in response to your added requirement:***

Here is an example implementing your 3 rules for populating the `NS1:Access` element. As I mentioned in a comment to your question, these rules are not collectively exhaustive - so you will need to add to them in order to cover all possible scenarios:

```
    <xsl:variable name="access" select="services/Access" />
    <NS1:Access>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- 1. all are Allow -->
            <xsl:when test="not($access != 'Allow')">Allow</xsl:when>
            <!-- 2. at least one is Reject  -->
            <xsl:when test="$access = 'Reject'">Reject</xsl:when>
            <!-- 3. all are  Reject_morepoint  -->
            <xsl:when test="not($access != 'Reject_morepoint')">Reject_morepoint</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </NS1:Access>
```

Comment: Would be lovely for us XSLT novices if you could explain why that "hack line" is bad :)

Comment: @JoelBodenmann I believe it has already been explained a number of times. In a nutshell, the presumption is that namespaces are there for a reason. If you ignore the namespace, you run the danger of a false positive match with another node having the same local name in a different namespace. Plus it's ugly.

Comment: @michael the solution will work fine for this particular incoming request. But i have that incoming XML is dynamic one meaning the  "Access" tag value can be either 1. Allow 2. Reject 3. Reject_morepoint.

Comment: @user5458829 See the addition to my post.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I think the solution is not quite working . As per the given Input . The output should be "<NS1:Access>Reject</NS1:Access>" as it is having atleast one reject . But as per your solution it is coming as  "<NS1:Access>Allow</NS1:Access>" .Please let me know the issue.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, because I am getting the expected result: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B6C

Comment: its working fine now . I made template match as <xsl:template match="/"> that was causing the issue. I have one more issue like how to get value for final <NS1:ErrorCode>200504</NS1:ErrorCode>. If all are Allow then it will be always 0 and if any one "AuthCheckType" is Reject then it Error code will be the same error code for that particular "AuthCheckType" and if all are "Reject_morepoint" then it will have the last error code of that  "AuthCheckType" . becaue every "AuthCheckType' is having different error code. Please let me know hot to get that error code in response.

Comment: You can place both `NS1:Access` and `NS1:ErrorCode` inside the `xsl:choose` block and populate them according to each test result.